# Is there a way to see or set the seed for Hades' runs?

Tags: hades

On speedruns.com, https://www.speedrun.com/hades#Any_Heat There's a seeded tab, and to post in the unseeded category, you have to show the last death, before the start of your run.

So is there a way to know/control the seed?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*Update*

It looks like there are a few seeded games listed now with the rule for seeded games:

> SEEDED RULES
>
> Can run on any seed (this can be managed using specific Profile saves or a save manager).

So it looks like you can 'share' a seed via save file manipulation.  Most likely this will be a PC only thing for now.  The previous answer still is valid.

---

There is currently no way to view/control the seed as far as I know, that is why the seeded tab remains empty.

However, there are ways to game the system.  Mostly using the 'give up' feature.  This allows you to restart the run with the exact same seed.

To get around that, speedrun is requiring all players to include the previous death at the beginning of the run to ensure that there was no 'exploring' done prior to the run and it is in fact a blind speedrun.

This is the only way they can to enforce rule #3 (bolded portion by me):

> 3. Must be a single, continuous run. No game quit-outs (Alt-F4s, **give-ups**, quits or crashes) mid-run.